# JSF ViewState lost in ajax call after form validation fails and form contains Primefaces outputPanel with deferred="true" attribute

Tags: jquery, ajax, primefaces, jsf-2.2, omnifaces

I have h:form inside p:dialog element which contains some form fields (e.g. name, description..) and one p:outputPanel with deferred="true" and deferredMode="load" and everything seems to work fine in best use-case scenario. Form is backed with viewscoped bean.

Problem occurs when I try to ajax submit the form (via p:commandButton) with some of the required form fields not filled in (or any other scenario where form validation will fail). After ajax response from server (with all form view elements updated including required fields marked as red...), p:outputPanel element inside form tries to load(update) itself but the ajax request sent by that p:outputPanel contains no javax.faces.ViewState. As I understand, this forces backing @ViewScoped bean to recreate, loosing any bean state and making displayed form invalid (e.g. some of the forms field was populated and they are preserved after validation failure, but after problematic 2nd ajax call even them are invalid..)

I found out that ViewState is missing in ajax call by using Fiddler proxy.

My actual scenario is a little bit complicated, but it boils down to the same problem. I use custom Primefaces component which extends p:outputPanel. I was thinking first that my component was bugged, but then i tried with simple p:outputPanel and got the same result.

So, is there a way to fix this somehow? Can I add ViewState manually? (FixViewState from omniFaces is not helping...)
Or maybe I am doing something very wrong?

Also, I use Mojarra JSF 2.2.11, Weld 2.2.8, PF 5.2, OmniFaces and Apache Tomcat 8.0

```
@Named("databean")
@ViewScoped
public class ViewScopedBackingBean implements Serializable{

    private String name;

    public void add(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Yuhu :)");
    }

    // ...
}
```

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:inputText value="#{databean.name}" required="true" />
        <p:outputPanel id="deferredPanel" deferred="true" deferredMode="load">
            <h:outputText value="Name: #{databean.name}" />
        </p:outputPanel>
        <p:commandButton id="addBtn" value="Add"
            actionListener="#{databean.add}" update="@form" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<resource-env-ref>
    <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.CLIENT_SIDE_VALIDATION</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>bootstrap</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Please create an mcve. See [ask] and the jsf info page

Comment: Thanks. I don't see anything weird, let me try your code tomorrow and see what happens

Comment: What BalusC tries to make explicit is: is it **minimal**, meaning you cannot remove anything anymore and still have it fail

Comment: @BalusC Ok, I removed **everything** I can think of... I don't know what to say. Maybe I actually do not know something very essential about JSF and I am not even aware of that.. But anyway, I still don't know what is wrong here :(

Comment: OK, I tested it, but I can't reproduce it. The ViewState parameter is present in both the HTTP request payload and in the HTML DOM tree. You mentioned that you've only checked the HTTP request payload in Fiddler. To exclude one and other, can you please also check HTML DOM tree? Rightclick and *Inspect Element* in webbrowser (or press F12 and tab to "Elements" or "Document", depending on webbrowser; note that the "Network"/"Net" tab basically shows same detail as Fiddler, perhaps you wasn't aware of that either)

Comment: Shoot, I've been just doing the same. Luckily with the same result as BalusC. Only with Mojarra 2.2.10 on Wildfly 8.2 (no Tomcat install directly available)

Comment: @BalusC and Kukeltje: Ok, can it be then something about my environment? I of course checked DOM. ViewState is present in HTML DOM all the time, but it changes its value after deferred `<p:outputPanel>` made its ajax call after validation fails. Also, network tab in Chrome shows same as Fiddler: in ajax call sent by `<p:commandButton>` (javax.faces.source:j_idt4:addBtn) javax.faces.ViewState is present in Form Data, but when ajax call is made by deferred panel (javax.faces.source:j_idt4:deferredPanel) there is no ViewState in Form Data, but is present in same ajax call response, with new value

Comment: Do you have any settings in `web.xml` which are different from defaults?

Comment: @BalusC, I added `web.xml` in question. I guess there is nothing special about it?

Comment: @BalusC and Kukeltje: Ok, I spent some time trying different env. setup, but still no luck. I tried Tomcats 7 & 8, MyFaces & Mojarra for JSF implementation, Weld and no Weld (javax.faces.bean.*) for CDI, with different versions of all of that, and I still get the same result - Every time I hit "Add" button and validation fails (name filed left empty), ViewScoped bean gets recreated. I feel like I'am hitting a wall here. I don't know how come that i am getting different results than you two :/ . Any hints what I might try?

Comment: Which webbrowser? Cookies enabled? Trashed all cookies before testing?

Comment: @BalusC Yeah, all that. I created .war and also tried it on PC in my office, sent it to some friends.. always the same: anytime you click "add" button without filling in name field in form (validation fails), view scoped bean gets recreated. Or.. just a sec.. can I rely that `@PostConstruct` is called when bean is (re)created?

Comment: Well, I (and Kukeltje) can't reproduce it. We are both JSF experts and know what we do. This sounds too much like you're not actually using JSF 2.2 and have multiple JSF API/impl versions in webapp's runtime classpath conflicting each other. This broken view state problem is explainable for an older JSF 2.0/2.1 impl, but not for 2.2. I would still only wonder why fixviewstate.js didn't work. But alas, it's hard to tell without having a true MCVE at hands. Perhaps you can drop that .war somewhere?

Comment: @BalusC Ok, I made some db link here: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wc79vi7kgqc5ygv/test-app.war?dl=0). This is version without Weld. I hope this is not against SO rules. I know that you and Kukeltje are experts, and that is why I am worried, because I know that problem is on my side but I can't find it.

Comment: Curious, I can reproduce it with the given WAR. I will check later when I have time and opportunity.

Comment: @BalusC & Kukeltje. Any luck finding some spare time to look into this? I am stuck and will probably have to look for workaround if I don't figure out what is the problem here.